# What Gradle commands are Android Studio running when I click Run?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I click 'Run' in Android Studio, I want to know what specific Gradle command-line is being executed. Through the Gradle Console it shows you the results of what's being executed, but not the command-line task and arguments. I'm specifically interested in what the Gradle command-line arguments are when unit tests are ran on a specific package, method, or class.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to see the actual executed `gradle` command in Android Studio, however if you're only interested in running specific unit tests here's how.

To run all unit tests within a package:

```
./gradlew testAppDebug --tests="*.my.package.name.*"
```

Or a single class

```
./gradlew testAppDebug --tests="*.my.package.name.MyClassTest"
```

Or a single test method (in our case named `simpleTest`):

```
./gradlew testAppDebug --tests="*.my.package.name.MyClassTest.simpleTest"
```

Hope it helps :)